# Isn't the potential drop across a silicon diode always 0.7 V?

Tags: voltage, resistors, diodes

While simulating the circuits, as seen in the first circuit below: [image: circuit]

The voltage drop across the silicon diode in this case is 0.7 V, but for some other simulations, the voltage drop isn't 0.7 V. Why could this be the case?

In the second circuit: [image: circuit2]

The voltage drop across the second silicon diode happens to be 0.8 V.

And in another simulations, after getting rid of the resistor in circuit 3 below, the voltage drop across the Si diodes isn't 0.7 V.
[image]

Comment: "0.7V" is a rule of thumb, as such it fails often. Consider a more nuanced model, such as a Thevenin source (fixed voltage + incremental resistance), or a logarithmic (nonlinear dependent) source plus resistance.

Comment: First and third pictures are "logical". Second is not.

Comment: Your third schematic is a magic smoke generator.

Comment: A simulation is not reality.  We assume 0.7V so we can do calculations.

Comment: The problem is not only the 0.7 V. <<<How to explain that one diode is 0.7 V and the other is 0.8 V? >>> Check your format of displaying numbers ... More digits (at least 2) should be needed for display. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cm45y.png